# Does any paper use energy harvest to in the baseband?

Tags: digital-communications

Most of RF energy harvest system just harvest $\rho$  of the RF signal for charging the battery,and the other part RF energy will be processed to baseband signal by RF Chain to do the information decoding,like this below
[image]

Now i have a new thinking,if we receive signal and use the RF chain to let the signal become the baseband signal first,then use the power splitter to let $\rho$ of baseband signal power to charge the battery(energy harvest).Can we do that?

[image]

Is there any paper which use this method to do the energy harvest?like this below

Comment: I am only familiar with harvesting in RFID tags so I don't know what rho is and how the blocks are implemented. But: can you run "RF chain" without power? Otherwise you may have a startup problem.

Comment: RF chain should also have a power supply,here i will use battery as a power supply,however,i can't know how much power should RF chain need,so here i won;t discuss the power that RF chain needed

Comment: Usually 100% of the power that comes out of the RF chain comes from the RF chain's power supply. There are active electronics in there. Using the output of an electronic circuit to recharge the electronic circuit won't work. But maybe someone has invented one that doesn't work like that.

Comment: @user253751 so you mean that  if i use the battery as  power supply of RF chain,the output power of RF chain still mainly from the battery,not the received signal from antenna? why?

Comment: @carewe The RF chain is more-or-less a kind of analog computer. The outputs from a computer come from the computer's power supply, they aren't connected to the inputs of the computer. It's the same reason you can't charge the battery from after the information decoding stage.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Your question neglects the fact that a mixer can't transfer the whole received power to baseband (mixers are typically active, and most of the baseband energy comes from the LO that the device has to generate itself).

You can use any nonlinear device, even one without an external power source, but the mixed output's energy will always be way lower than the energy of the inputs, simply by the pure math behind what mixing does.

In general, when asking such question, you'd start with "where does what energy come from?", and with a clean, and simplified, block diagram of the receive RF chain including the mixer, and that would have answered that. If you're researching power harvesting, this is the MAIN thing you'll need to understand!